# Issue with SQL Select value

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on an IP banning script at the moment which includes an appeal system. I am just having one little problem with the value returned from a settings table in the database.

In `class.Database.inc.php` I have the following function relevant to this issue:

```
     /**
   * Function to see if the appeal option has been enabled
   * @return 1 or 0
   */
  public function AppealSysOn()
  {
      $mysqli = $this->getConnection();
      $sql_query = "SELECT enabled FROM appeal_sys_settings WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1";
      $row = $mysqli->query($sql_query)->fetch_assoc() OR trigger_error(mysqli_error($mysqli), E_USER_ERROR);
      return $row;        

  }
```

Then in the `banned.php` file which is the file a banned IP will be redirected to I have this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Checks to see if the Appeal system is enabled or disabled.
 * If enabled then display appeal options, else, null.
 */
$Data = new Database();
if ($Data->AppealSysOn() == 1)
{
echo 'Would you like to make an appeal?';
// TODO........
}

?>
```

I have used `var_export` to view the value of `$row` and it shows `array ( 'enabled' => '1', )`. So from this I know that it is returning the correct value however it doesn't seem to work in the conditional. What could be the problem?

Comment: @scrowler It is there I must have accidently removed it before posting the question when I edited it. My bad.

Comment: Isn't it returning an associative array? And you're checking whether it is equal to an int ...

Comment: aside from the issue, you know IP does not equal person. one person can use many IP's and one IP could be thousands of different people.

Comment: @vch Oh yeah, whoops that flew right past me. Thank you for that.

Comment: Ok, in that case you need to `return $row['enabled'] === '1';` to return a boolean result for your query

Comment: @vch it's a loose comparison, so (int) 1 is == to (string) '1'

Comment: @scrowler, my point referred to `$row`, which is what he was returning.

Comment: Fixed, thank you and I really don't know why I didn't see that.